# What is the relationship between walk_forward_validation (WFV)/series_to_supervised (STS) with Direct/Recursive multi-step forecasting & Backtesting

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting, univariate

I'm experimenting with univariate time series using the following approaches that suit time-series analytics in order to transform the data in a way that the inputs to the model are the targets of previous K observations:

**1.** [lookback period](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-in-pytorch/), [example1](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-step-predictions-with-lstm-forecasting-hotel-revenues-c9ef0d3ef2df), [example2](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hassanamin/time-series-analysis-using-lstm-keras/notebook)

```py
#ِDataset matrix is formed
def create_dataset(df , lookback=1):
  data  = np.array(df.iloc[:, :-1])
  label = np.array(df.iloc[:, -1])
  #create X_train and Y_train and MinMaxScaler on Y_train
  X = list()
  Y = list()
  for i in range(lookback , len(data)):
      X.append(data[i-lookback:i])
      Y.append(label[i])
  X = np.array(X)
  Y = np.array(Y)
  Y=np.expand_dims(Y,-1) 
  return X,Y

# Lookback period
lookback = 5
X_train, Y_train = create_dataset(train, lookback)
X_val, Y_val = create_dataset(validation, lookback)
X_test, Y_test = create_dataset(test, lookback)
# print(X_train.shape , Y_train.shape)       #(155, 5, 1) (155, 1)
# print(X_val.shape, Y_val.shape)            #(35, 5, 1) (35, 1)
# print(X_test.shape, Y_test.shape)          #(69, 5, 1) (69, 1)
```

**2.** [transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset](https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-forest-for-time-series-forecasting/) posted by *Jason Brownlee*:

```py
# Finalize model and predict monthly births with random forest
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
 
# transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
 n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
 df = DataFrame(data)
 cols = list()
 # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
 for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
 cols.append(df.shift(i))
 # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
 for i in range(0, n_out):
 cols.append(df.shift(-i))
 # put it all together
 agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
 # Drop rows with NaN values
 if dropnan:
 agg.dropna(inplace=True)
 return agg.values
 
# load the dataset
series = read_csv('daily-total-female-births.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = series.values
# transform the time series data into supervised learning
train = series_to_supervised(values, n_in=6)
# split into input and output columns
trainX, trainy = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
```

**Qs:** The followings are my question to understand if the abovementioned methods have, e.g. `lookback` or `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) have some alignment with used methods on [skforecast](/questions/tagged/skforecast) package.

**Q1:** What is the difference between these two approaches? (*lookback period* Vs *transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset*)
I also tried in meantime `walk_forward_validation()` approach inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442740/multivariate-xgboost-time-series):

> Walk forward validation is a method for **estimating the skill of the model on out-of-sample data.** We contrive out of sample, and each time step one out of sample observation becomes in-sample. We can use the same model in ops, as long as the walk-forward is performed each time a new observation is received.

My observation shows no difference between using:

- just `series_to_supervised` (STS)
- `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) comparing outputs, especially MAE results, but a bit in quality of forecasting up & downs(could be due to weights during training):

[image: img]

**Q2:** Does `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) are equivalent to the following:

- [Recursive multi-step forecasting](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-time-series-forecasting-python-scikitlearn.html#Recursive-multi-step-forecasting)

[image: img]

- [Direct multi-step forecasting](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-time-series-forecasting-python-scikitlearn.html#Direct-multi-step-forecasting)

[image: img]

**Q3:**  Is there any alignment/equivalent using `walk_forward_validation` (WFV) & `series_to_supervised` (STS) with one of the following **Backtesting** ?

- [Backtesting **with** refit and increasing training size (fixed origin)](https://skforecast.org/0.7.0/user_guides/backtesting.html#backtesting-with-refit-and-increasing-training-size-fixed-origin)
  [image: img]
  [image: gif]
- [Backtesting **with** refit and fixed training size (rolling origin)](https://skforecast.org/0.7.0/user_guides/backtesting.html#backtesting-with-refit-and-fixed-training-size-rolling-origin)

[image: img]
[image: gif]

- [Backtesting without refit](https://skforecast.org/0.7.0/user_guides/backtesting.html#backtesting-without-refit)

[image: img]
[image: gif]

All pics sources in Q2 & Q3: credit from [*Joaquín Amat Rodrigo, Javier Escobar Ortiz*](https://www.cienciadedatos.net/documentos/py27-time-series-forecasting-python-scikitlearn.html#Direct-multi-step-forecasting)